# Connecting microstrategy to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, microstrategy

I have trouble connecting microstrategy to hive. 
I have followed every instruction [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/download/attachments/13928407/Cloudera_Connector_for_MicroStrategy_v1.0.1.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1328651355000)

I have read technical notes from microstrategy as well. I can connect successfully to port 8020, but when i run the query i get SQLget error. I am not able to explore the object s from the microstrategy server. I use the root account, so permission shouldnt be an issue. Also I create hive table as mentioned [here](http://simon-fortelny.com/2011/05/08/adding-hive-to-existing-hadoop-workflows/).

I am using the latest version of microstrategy and hadoop cdh3

I have been trying for weeks now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot a small step to enable the hive server. After I enable the hive server. I could access the HDFS!